# Native sql query in Excel fails everytime password changes, is there a way to make it ask for a password?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I use Excel to query one of my organization's large, secure databases. To help Excel pull the data faster, I used the option to use a sql statement. I then recorded a macro of me running the query and set it to button. I did all this because my coworkers aren't very tech-savvy, so just having a button they can push and get the info they need is important.

Everything worked great, until I had to do my monthly password change. When I ran the macro, the query failed due to the authentication being different. It's an easy enough change for me to go into the data source settings and update my credentials; but, even that's too advanced for the end user of this query.

Is there a way to have Excel prompt the user the for the user/password every time the query is run and use that to connect to the database? Or at least a way for a prompt to appear when the query fails?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: To answer the bot; this isn't really a problem with code, but more if there's a process to call the login dialog boxes from within power query.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
Sub IdentifyWorksheet()
    Dim UserName As String
    Dim PassWord As String
    UserName = InputBox("Please Enter Username:", "Login_", "username")
    PassWord = InputBox("Please Enter Password:", "Login_", "password")
    ' preform login operation using above variables.
End Sub
```